# How to create stored procs from the Redshift Python Connector

Tags: python, amazon-redshift, execute, connector

I have several stored procs saved in individual files in a local folder. I would like execute each file so the stored procs are created in Redshift. I'm using the following code but it doesn't seem to be working. It doesn't throw any errors -  I just don't see the created proc in Redshift. Can this be done?

```html
#Connect to the cluster
import redshift_connector
import os

conn = redshift_connector.connect(
     host='xx',
     database='xx',
     port=xx,
     user='xxx',
     password='xxx'
  )
  
# Create a Cursor object
cursor = conn.cursor()

path = "C:\\Tmp"
os.chdir(path)

def run_stored_proc(file_path):
    with open(file_path, 'r') as f:
        stored_proc =  f.read()
        try:
            cursor.execute(stored_proc)
        except Exception as e:    
            print(e)


# iterate through stored procs in the folder
for file in os.listdir():
    # Check whether file is a sql file
    if file.endswith(".SQL"):
        file_path = f"{path}\{file}"
  
        # run the proc
        run_stored_proc(file_path)
```